# RewriteRule to file in folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a htaccess file which I use on other website, but this time it doesn't work.
I have;
`RewriteRule ^this$ testarea/that.php`
But it doesn't find the file, it gives an empty page.
How can I redirect an url to a file in a folder?
Thanks in advance!

#### Update:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^this$ testarea/that.php
```

This is all I have in my .htaccess file.
I want my url to look like;

`www.mywebsite.ext/this`

instead of;

`www.mywebsite.ext/testarea/that.php`

Thats all I want.

The .htaccess works now, the problem was that I saved it as a wrong file extension..
But now the images and stylesheets won't work, how can I fix this?

Comment: What is your folder structure? And what URL are you typing in the address bar?

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess file is being read? Try writing some invalid string to your .htaccess file (like "asdf") and call the page again. If you're getting an internal server error, it's being read, otherwise, your problem is that the .htaccess isn't being used by apache. In which case you should check your apache configuration and make your your .htaccess file is in the right place.

Comment: See edit^ * keystrokes *

Comment: @Chris Where should I put the 'asdf', I'm not familiar with htaccess :)

Comment: @Jay Wit: Did you place the htaccess file in the root of your website? Also, you are currently rewriting, not redirecting.

Comment: @Jay Wit: Just temporarily remove all of its contents and place the "asdf" in the file.

Comment: @Michiel Pater; Yes it's in the root of my website (httpdocs). And I didn't get an error.

Comment: Then you're going to have to be more specific with what you're trying to do. Please update your question with an example of what you're trying to achieve, as we cannot determine if ^this$ is a valid RewriteRule in your case.

Comment: @Jay Wit: Your webhost may not have enabled htaccess usage or mod_rewrite. I suggest sending an e-mail to ask them for help.

Comment: @Chris; Original post updated, I really don't know what to describe more about it..  
@Michiel Pater; Isn't there an other solution to check it out? I don't have the time to wait for their response, it's for a client.

Comment: They may also not have mod_rewrite activated. You could check for that module by dumping a phpinfo();

Comment: @Jay Wit: Can you try this in your rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^this$ /testarea/that.php`

Comment: @Jay Wit: Did you use `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: Then your .htaccess should work. I'm guessing the paths aren't correct. Make sure the path to _that_ is correct. Try using the absolute path from the document root.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the path is correct. Also the absolute path(`http://blalblas.....`) didn't work either. I'm working on a subdomain btw, don't know if it has anything to do with it (`test.mywebsite.ext`)

Comment: What happens if you navigate to: `www.mywebsite.ext/this`?

Comment: Don't know what else to suggest except maybe creating a standalone test case on the top level domain, then when that works move on to the subdomain and see if you notice any difference.

Comment: @Jay Wit: I would suggest using this rule first: `RewriteRule ^this /testarea/that.php [R=302,L]`

Comment: @Michiel; Nothing, it redirects me to `www.mywebsite.ext`.. @Chris; They won't give us access to the top level domain, don't know why.. @anubhava; Doesn't work either

Comment: @Jay Wit: Ok now please see if following rule works: `RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]` If your .htaccess is being used then you should get 404 for **EVERY** request. Once that is working go backwards.

Comment: I feel so stupid.. I stupidly didn't save the htaccess file a a .htaccess file... But I have another issue, the stylesheets, images etc aren't found. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is "that" an HTML file? If so, you're going to have to either change the paths therein to start where "this" was, or use a Redirect instead of a Rewrite.

Comment: @Chris; That is a php file, but I the Rewrite rule works now, the stylesheet and other items aren't included though. Using the absolute path is too much work now, and adding a base url always messes with or without the "www.", so is there an other solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a CNAME record in your DNS settings to point `www` to `@` it should work perfectly. Also, make sure you enter `http://` in the base url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess works now, the problem was that I saved it as a wrong file extension..
*'But now the images and stylesheets won't work, how can I fix this?'*
I fixed this problem by adding the `<base ...` tag..